# A Php Error was encountred Severity: Warning Message in_array() expect parameter 2 to be array CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm programming with Codeigniter.
I have an error.

> A Php Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message in_array() expect parameter 2 to be array

I have compared the code with another that works but I have not found the error.

[image: POST]

```
    public function update($post_id)
    {      
        if(!in_array('updatePost', $this->permission)) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

        if(!$post_id) {
            redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
        }

            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('post_name'),
                'summary' => $this->input->post('summary'),
                'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'subject_id' => json_encode($this->input->post('subjects')),
                'tag_id' => json_encode($this->input->post('tag')),
                'category_id' => $this->input->post('categories'),
                'availability' => $this->input->post('availability'),
            );

            if($_FILES['post_image']['size'] > 0) {
                $upload_image = $this->upload_image();
                $upload_image = array('image' => $upload_image);

                $this->model_posts->update($upload_image, $post_id);
            }

            $update = $this->model_posts->update($data, $post_id);
            if($update == true) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Successfully updated');
                redirect('posts/', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('errors', 'Error occurred!!');
                redirect('posts/update/'.$post_id, 'refresh');
            }
        }
        else {

            $this->data['subjects'] = $this->model_subjects->getActiveSubjects();         
            $this->data['tag'] = $this->model_tag->getActiveTag();           
            $this->data['categories'] = $this->model_categories->getActiveCategory();          

            $post_data = $this->model_posts->getPostData($post_id);
            $this->data['post_data'] = $post_data;
            $this->render_template('posts/edit', $this->data); 
        }   
    }
```

edit //Post form

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="tag">Tag</label>
                  <?php $tag_data = json_decode($post_data['tag_id']); ?>
                  <select class="form-control select_group" id="tag" name="tag[]" multiple="multiple">
                    <?php foreach ($tag as $k => $v): ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $v['id'] ?>" <?php if(in_array($v['id'], $tag_data)) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $v['name'] ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

Comment: The variable is NULL, not an array. Check with `empty` prior to usage.

Comment: Why one long line of PHP? You'll hate yourself later when you come back to this code and have to do maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is telling you exactly what is wrong. In your case, because your second parameter is `$tag_data`, and `$tag_data` is the result of `json_decode`, it's likely that `json_decode` had a problem trying to decode `$post_data['tag_id']`.

The PHP documentation for json_decode states:

> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data
>   is deeper than the recursion limit.

See here for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

You could do something like this to get around the warning:

```
if( is_array( $tag_data ) && in_array($v['id'], $tag_data) )
```

But the bigger question here is why are you doing this? There's probably a better way.

Answer (score 0):

the tag_id in database need to be an actual array in this form ["1","2",..]